# How can I get the resources from this SWF flash file? Or at least resize it?

Tags: flash, swf, resources, decompile

Usually I can grab a SWF from firefox's tools --> page info --> media section. Then I can decompile it with sothink decompiler, and save the resources.

But this one flash site is different ...when I decompile it, the resources are nothing like what's on the site. I can find the graphics in firefox's cache, but only at low resolution.

What I want to do is get a full-resolution version of some wine bottles on the flash site. The script that creates this graphic seems to resize it to fit my screen. Nothing I do allows me to enlarge it. Firefox's zoom doesn't. Changing the CSS container doesn't. Saving a local copy of the page and editing the javascript doesn't.

Can someone tell me 1. Is there a trick to enlarge the site, locally or not, and 2. Is there really a larger graphic of the wine bottle on the site, or hidden in the SWF file?

The page is here: 
http://www.leplangt.com/main.php

To see the wine bottle click "what" and then "gt-x".

Comment: Are you asking someone to aid you in stealing images from some's website?

Comment: no, I work for a reseller and I have to make ads to help sell their wine. Trying to work directly with them is tough due to the language barrier, and they don't have contact info for the site designer. It wouldn't be useful to 'steal' the bottle image, as it has their wine label all over it. If I just needed an image of a bottle I'd go to google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they have protected the swf, that'd be quite involved. (I guess would be easiest just to contact them in english so they pass you super high resolution versions) There are free extraction tools like http://www.swftools.org

If Sothink could not extract it, chances are low for other tools, but you never know, I would try.

Comment: what I think is happening is this: you know how the SWF in a typical youtube clip doesn't contain the actual movie, it's just some small player and the actual stream must be downloaded separately? I think this flash is the same way. The SWF ("peaceofcake.swf") doesn't have any of the graphics or animations embedded. It's just a framework and it grabs graphics off the website. I'm hoping there's a hi-res version of these graphics and it either scales them on the fly or grabs one of several versions based on your monitor size.

Comment: It could be using the swf as a flv player, yes. But I am also inclined to think the swf "player" actually calls a php, which serves de images, probably at some folder of the domain. And that is surely protected. Not probably the swf. So, one way or the other, seems is a matter of using Google translator after getting their answer, and use some imagination to get the sense of sentences ;)

Comment: IMHO they have just those images in some folder of their web server, and they don't even know as the designer made it in the past, in just that domain, so just I'd ask your client that, or/and ask them giving you access to the server, if they are less tech savy and agree with that.

Comment: Makes sense. In the end we did have to go with translated email. Worked out fine. Thanks for checking in.